# Swift Timer Loop doesn't trigger but view and controller are connected

Tags: swift, loops, timer

I'm trying to print the title "⚡️FlashChat" one letter at a time.
I'm coding along with a video and I've checked my code against the instructor's and it matches.
Right now, the title prints in its entirety when the sim is built.
I've adjusted the `withTimeInterval` to see fit that was set too quickly.
If I remove the loop and just execute the `titleLabel.text = ""`, the title disappears, so it is connected correctly.

Thanks in advance!

```swift
import UIKit

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        titleLabel.text = ""
        
        var charIndex = 0.0
        let titleText = "⚡FlashChat"
        for letter in titleText {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 7.0
                * charIndex, repeats: false) {(timer)
                in
                self.titleLabel.text?.append(letter)}
        }
        charIndex += 1
        
    }
    
}
```

[image: Code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're incrementing `charIndex` outside your `for` loop. So interval will always be equal to `0`